Suppress light-locker "Password" string during login
I've installed lightdm and light-locker in Debian 12 (no desktop environment but I've also installed xorg and i3).
After I enter my password and press enter from the lockscreen I reach with "light-locker-command -l" a string that says Password appears at the bottom of the login box (red box in the image below). Is it possible to remove this string? Note that it does not appear when lightdm is run directly (upon starting the system or logging off).
Undesired Password string enclosed in red box
